# Local (non-root) installation folder

Tags: unity, 16.04

I am trying to make an application. Currently I am using the following directories during installation:

`/usr/share/applications` is where I drop `software.desktop`

`/usr/share/icons` is where I drop `icon.svg`

`/usr/share/mime/packages` is where I drop my `mime.xml` file.

Since those are the only times during install that require root access, I was wondering if the were equivalent, non root directories, where I could throw these files and they would get pickeup by the system (Unity launcher for instance).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The respective user-specific directories are all in `~/.local/share` (`~` is the current user's home directory):

- `~/.local/share/applications`
- `~/.local/share/icons`
- `~/.local/share/mime`

All those directories have the same purpose as the ones in `/usr/share` except that their effect is limited to the specific user and that you do not need root rights to write in them.

Comment: I don't seem to have the folder `~/.local/share/mime` in my system.

Comment: I have one and it's quite filled. Just try and create the folder and put your files in there. Maybe it works? I don't know if there is anything more needed to initialize the directory.